How to make Kafka producer to send multiple records in one go or in a single batch containing multiple messages
I have explored many tutorials but could not find the exact way to send multiple messages in one go to Kafka broker.
Example:
I want to send List employees using Kafka producer
producer.send(topicName, employees);
I don't want records to be sent one by one, like running a loop and calling send method each time.
Could someone help me with the best way to achieve the same?

First, what specific errors are you getting? If you use json, for example, list objects send fine... Can you clarify what you're expecting to consume? A list object, per record or individual records? Calling send will always send exactly one message. That list will be serialized and sent, rather than broken apart. You'll need a loop for individual records, but kafka network protocol does batch multiple records together

I am not getting any error as I am not able to send list of records in one go. I need to loop them and then call send method again and again. And if I create a parent object and inside it take the list of records and then send parent object, then its size is increasing. I want to send List parameter or what would be the better approach?

If you're "not able", I would suspect there would be an error. Kafka has a ListSerializer for this purpose, or as mentioned, json/avro should be able to serialize lists too, without any wrapper object, but if the consumer expects to read individual employee records, the list will have to be broken apart by the producer

This is at producer end only. I could not find a method or any way in a kafkaTemplate to send list of records. I am using kraft mode and the kafka version is 3.7.0

ListSerializer is a builtin class you can set as the value.serializer property, but that'll send the entire list at once, rather than one for each element
